# sketching f(x,y) domains

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I was given the following:

$$f(x,y)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (xy)^{n}$$

and told to find the domain and sketch it. I know the domain (i think? ) is all real numbers but I'm not sure how to go about graphing that. Any help would go a long way.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a geometric series with $r = xy$, so it is defined only when $|r| = |xy| < 1$.

Comment: converges for |xy|<1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments what you have is a geometric series that converges when $|xy|<1$. To figure out what this looks like consider a few cases.

$$x>0,y>0$$

$$x<0,y<0$$

$$x>0, y<0$$

$$x<0, y>0$$

$$x \ \text{and} \ \text{or} \ y \ \text{are} \ 0$$

And graph each part separately, then join them.

For example, looking at the third case $x>0,y<0$ we have $xy<0$, and $|xy|=-xy<1$. So we graph $y>\frac{-1}{x}$ in the fourth quadrant excluding the axes.

Or you can consider cases again on inequality,

$$-1<xy<1$$